# dynamic output for SHOW PROCESSLIST in mysql using JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I know that using JDBC we can create output for queries inside a database, but how can I get the output of the command `SHOW PROCESSLIST` as an output of a Java program.

In mysql we get it by: `SHOW PROCESSLIST`

But I was wondering if we can generate the output using Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use executeQuery for getting **SHOW PROCESSLIST** ResultSet.

```
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql", "root", password);
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {
                stmt = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SHOW PROCESSLIST");
                while (rs.next())
                {
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("Host"));
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("Id"));
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("User"));
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("db"));
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("Command"));
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("state"));
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("info"));
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your MySQL version, you can perform a select on

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST;
```

and you can do a where between the user, database, and host IP.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST WHERE db ="mycase" AND HOST LIKE "192.168.11.174%"
```

Comment: dont you think there should be an explanation of why you think this could be an answer.